# Griffiths Consistent histories MQS state in Mach-Zehnder experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-interpretations, superposition, interferometry

In Robert B. Griffiths' Consistent Quantum Theory, he describes a variant of the Mach-Zehnder interferometer experiment where a detector represented by "off" state $\lvert 1\hat{e}\rangle$ and "triggered" state  $\lvert 1\hat{e}\rangle$ placed on one arm $e$ of the output of the interferometer.  He shows there is a consistent family of histories that have a superposition of states at times after the particle leaves the interferometer of either (quoting roughly from Griffiths):
"

$$\lvert mr\rangle = \frac{ \lvert me,1\hat{e}\rangle + \lvert mf,0\hat{e}\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}$$,

or:

$$\lvert ms\rangle = \frac{ -\lvert me,1\hat{e}\rangle + \lvert mf,0\hat{e}\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}$$

are superpositions of states in which the detector has and has not been triggered, so that they are macro quantum superposition states (MQS).... This MQS state is hard to interpret, and their counterparts for a real Mach-Zehnder or neutron interferometer are impossible to observe in the laboratory..."

If these superposition states are contained in time points of a consistent family of histories why isn't this a suitable description of the system?  Why is it impossible to observe in the lab?
Any clarification is helpful.

Comment: Without any disrespect to Griffiths, this sounds like a slightly modernized version of Schroedinger's cat. If that's the case, then the entire idea suffers from the same problem as the original: it simply can't believe that the universe provides more than enough irreversibility to make seemingly random outcomes a triviality. In reality there is no such thing as a triggered-and-non-triggered detector. A measurement is, by definition, a record that exists forever, i.e. it forces nature to make a classical binary choice. In the words of Yoda: "Do. Or do not. There is no try.".